# Is there a way to delete a collection in firebase with react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was looking at the docs, but they just have this stated:

```
// Deleting collections from a Web client is not recommended.
```

For reference, I'm moving a document from 1 collection to another and that document has subcollections.

To move it I do the following:

1. set the new document (`path` is a path to the new collection to place the doc in)
2. copy the collections from the old document to the new document

```
      setDoc(doc(db, path), inquiry);
      console.log(updatesCollection);
      updatesCollection.docs.map((updateDocument) => {
        (async () => (addDoc(collection(db, `/closed/${id}/updates`), updateDocument.data())))();
      });
```

3. delete the old document

```
(async () => await deleteDoc(doc(db, "active/" + id)))();
```

this leaves the old path open and the subcollection still there, is there a way I can delete it? this is a full react app so I want to do it client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this leaves the old path open and the subcollection still there

That's indeed the expected behavior since deleting a document doesn't mean that all subcollections that exist within that document will be deleted as well.

As the error message states:

> Deleting collections from a Web client is not recommended.

Don't do that. If you want to delete a document along with all the documents within its subcollections, please note that you have to do it [manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections).

Comment: if users delete posts, then I need to delete the subcollection, I can't go and delete each of the subcollections manually, is there no way to do this?

Comment: Not manually in the Firebase Console, nobody does that :) Manually means that you have to write code for that. Have you checked the documentation? You have to iterate through the subcollection, remove each document, and right after that delete the document. Is it ok now?

Comment: ah okay, yeah thats fine.